# How do I display base64 inside map loop(assumption) in ReactJS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, axios, react-bootstrap-table

I have a REST API that returns an image when I request with the url + (plus) file name and I want to display it in the image column in a table.

I use:
axios **0.18.0** 
reacj **16.13.0** 
react-bootstrap-table2-toolkit **1.3.1**

My assumption is that react-bootstrap-table2-toolkit works like map function.

I have column that will render image like this:

```
{
      dataField: 'img_url',
      text: 'Image',
      formatter: (cell, row) => {
        let renderPosts = async () => {
          try {
            let res = await axios.get('https://myApiUrl:6601/'+cell,{
              responseType: 'arraybuffer' 
            });
            let posts = _imageEncode(res.data);
            console.log(posts)
            return <img src={`data:image/jpeg;base64,${posts}`} />
          } catch (err) {
            console.log(err);
          }
        }
        
        return renderPosts()
      } 
    },
```

But I got error like this:

> Objects are not valid as a React child (found: [object Promise]). If you meant to render a collection of children, use an array instead.

### UPDATE

I changed the method above. by making this function outside of render() function

```
getImg = async (cell) => {
    try {
      let res = Promise.resolve(axios.get('https://myApiUrl:6601/'+cell,{
              responseType: 'arraybuffer' 
            }));
      return res.then(res=>{
        let mimetype="image/jpeg"
        let x =`data:${mimetype};base64,${btoa(String.fromCharCode(...new Uint8Array(res.data)))}`
        console.log(x)
        return x
      })
    } catch (err) {
      console.log(err);
    }
  }
```

then I use getImg() function inside **formatter** like this

```
{
      dataField: 'img_url',
      text: 'Image',
      formatter: (cell, row) => {
        let x = async () => await this.getImg(cell)
        return <img src={`${x()}`} />
      },
    },
```

but I got [object Promise] like this:
[image]

**I mean just want to retrieve the result string from conversion to base64**

I still new to this problem,
hope you can help, thanks:)

Comment: @Felix I tried, but still get the same error

Comment: Why not fetch all data beforehand? I would move the api call out of the rendering function, leaving the rest as it is.

Comment: @SagiRika I tried, I even tried dispatching actions using redux, I still get the same error..

Comment: @SagiRika I Tried again, does'nt have error. But  now I got ```[object Promise]``` inside my ```<img src="[object Promise]" />``` tag.

Comment: @SagiRika may you can help.. if you have any solution for this, please answer below:)

Comment: Show me your new code and ill try to help

Comment: @SagiRika I just updated the question above, thank you for wanting to help ...

Comment: `getImg` is still returning a promise. You are returning a promise, and then chaining it with then. Instead, you might await res in the function, then parse and return x.

Comment: @HaveSpacesuit ya I think you right, my function returning Promise. I tried as you said, but still got Promise..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see 2 problems in your updated method.

First one is, `getImg` is not returning a promise. You are using `Promise.resolve`, but `Promise.resolve` is meant to be called at the end of the function with `return`, so you can't attach `.then` to it. Also, if you're using `async`, there is no need for any `Promise` syntax. Change `getImg` to this:

```
getImg = async (cell) => {
  try {
    let res = await axios.get('https://myApiUrl:6601/'+cell,{
      responseType: 'arraybuffer' 
    });
    let mimetype="image/jpeg"
    let x =`data:${mimetype};base64,${btoa(String.fromCharCode(...new Uint8Array(res.data)))}`;
    console.log(x);
    return x;
  } catch (err) {
    console.log(err);
  }
}
```

Second thing is, you are creating a new function on each `formatter` loop, and it's redundant. Try this code:

```
dataField: 'img_url',
text: 'Image',
formatter: async (cell, row) => {
  const x = await this.getImg(cell);
  return <img src={`${x}`} />
},
```

I recommend you read more about promises, async functions and the (syntax) differences between the two.

[Promises](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise)

[Async Functions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function)

Please note that the `formatter` function must wait for the promises, and I'm not sure it does.

Let me know if you have any more questions.

Comment: thank you for your answer.. I have tried your answer, I think it is approaching success. because when I ```console.log (x)``` in the ```formatter()``` it returns a base64 string. but i still get this error:
```Error: Objects are not valid as a child React (found: [object Promise]). If you meant to render a collection of children, use an array instead.``` @SagiRika

Comment: That probably means that `react-bootstrap-table2-toolkit` doesn't support async rendering. Maybe there's a prop you can add, check their docs.

Comment: yes i think maybe the formatter doesn't support async function. I have read the documentation, and in the documentation it is explained that as much as possible to avoid the things that I did above. maybe I will look for other alternatives, or maybe you have other alternative suggestions? if there is I will be very grateful. and before that I thank you very much, brother..